# Mpdf not updating to latest version

Tags: php, mpdf

**My issue**

I am trying to create a pdf file using MPDF but after I installed mpdf I get the following error that it uses depricated curly braces. This is because php does not support curly braces instead of braces to specify the index since 8.0.0.

**What I tried**

- change the curly braces to brackets but this broke the library completely

The errors I am getting after fixing the depricated curly braces are the following:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 30572

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\classes\ttfontsuni.php:613 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\classes\ttfontsuni.php(202): TTFontFile->extractInfo(false, true, 0) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php(3880): TTFontFile->getMetrics('C:/xampp/htdocs...', 'dejavuserifcond...', 0, false, true, 0) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php(4246): mPDF->AddFont('dejavuserifcond...', '') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php(13621): mPDF->SetFont('dejavuserifcond...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php(1287): mPDF->SetDefaultFont('serif') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\pdf_genereren.php(8): mPDF->__construct() #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Jaar2\Project_webshop\Library\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\classes\ttfontsuni.php on line 613
```

- reinstalled the library twice, reinstalled composer once
- Upgrade to the latest stable php version (8.0.1)

```
<?php
ob_clean();
ob_start();

$rapport = ob_get_clean();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1>Hello world..</h1>");
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: mPDF is supported on PHP 8 since v8.0.10, there is no need to use a dedicated branch.

---

Turned out, because php8 is not supported yet in mpdf. I had to install a custom version of mpdf by doing `composer require mpdf/mpdf dev-php8-support` and that fixed all the issues.

Comment: can you explain how to do this ?

Comment: Just update to the latest version of mpdf, mpdf is supporting php 8 for a long time now.

Comment: yeah.. already did that and its working but the HTML is broken and not the same design in pdf as made in html